# Java Kafka stream processing tumbling windows

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am processing a stream of messages using Java KStream APIs. Currently I my code emits to get the output every 5 mins, but I want to get the out put at the top of the 5 min interval ( i.e 17:10, 17:15 etc)

Currently the interval depends on the time the program started. If the program starts at 17:08 the data gets collected at 17:13, 17:18, 17:23 etc intervals.

Is there a way that I can schedule so the data gets emitted at 5 min intervals which are multiples of 5?

```
class WindowedTransformerExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

final String stateStoreName = "stateStore";
final StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, String>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
    Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(stateStoreName),
        Serdes.String(),
        Serdes.String());

builder.addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder);

   builder.<String, String>stream("topic").transform(new 
     WindowedTransformer(stateStoreName), stateStoreName)
    .filter((k, v) -> k != null && v != null)
       // Here's where you do something with records emitted after 10 minutes
    .foreach((k, v)-> System.out.println());
}


static final class WindowedTransformer implements TransformerSupplier<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>> {

private final String storeName;

public WindowedTransformer(final String storeName) {
     this.storeName = storeName;
}

@Override
public Transformer<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>> get() {
  return new Transformer<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>>() {
    private KeyValueStore<String, String> keyValueStore;
    private ProcessorContext processorContext;

    @Override
    public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
      processorContext = context;
      keyValueStore = (KeyValueStore<String, String>) context.getStateStore(storeName);
      // could change this to PunctuationType.STREAM_TIME if needed
      context.schedule(Duration.ofMinutes(5), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, (ts) -> {
        try(final KeyValueIterator<String, String> iterator = keyValueStore.all()) {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
              final KeyValue<String, String> keyValue = iterator.next();
              processorContext.forward(keyValue.key, keyValue.value);
            }
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<String, String> transform(String key, String value) {
      if (key != null) {
        keyValueStore.put(key, value);
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
  };
  }
}
```

}